# How to rename solution and dll in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Help please, I have 2 projects linked between them, and one of them have also a dll included. After i renamed the name of one project, the solution and the dll name for the second one are the same. How can i modify them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those settings are controlled by the Project Properties dialog, not the project name. Look for the linker output settings.

You can rename a solution's display name in the Solution Explorer. Renaming a solution's filename is more complicated, but rename the *.sln file and the *.suo file, and any other files with the same name.

If you rename a VC project's filename, be sure to manually edit the *.sln file in Notepad to ensure the references are kept.

Comment: Dai, thanks so much for the answer but I can't figure it out. Please help me out with renaming it from [Proiect][Alionte Andreea][1044][Main] to simple [Proiect] . This is the transfer link for the project http://we.tl/NM3XCmfd38

Comment: can you help me and email me back on this email: ananas_alex@yahoo.com . please :((

Comment: Visual Studio > Solution Explorer > {your project} right click menu > Project Properties, you'll find everything you need there.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for VS2005, but I don't think this changed too much. There, the project files were actually XML files, and in cases of mass changes like renames, using a text editor on them was the better approach. Just do a search'n'replace on the file to change names of e.g. output files. Further, when using an existing project file as template for another project, make sure you delete the UUID at the top. VS will automatically regenerate the UUID but it gets confused if it finds two projects with the same.

Concerning the solution files, these are also text files that can be edited, but those actually referenced the projects by their UUID (if I remember correctly). In most cases, it's just easier to regenerate these files, i.e. start a new solution and add the projects.